# Two monitor setup

Tags: drivers, multiple-monitors, gpu-driver

I have a legacy NVIDIA card and two monitors: one of them is Onboard and the other is Offboard. Ubuntu only recognizes the Offboard one and the other one says no signal. I tried to install so much drivers but doesn't work... When I remove the Graphics card and connect the "Offboard" monitor at the motherboard it works... I really like Linux but problems like this is what makes gamers away from install it.

Comment: Yes, you're totally right. I am experiencing a very similar problem and even though I tried everything, it's still not working. Ubuntu should really make such bugs disappear, since it can be very frustrating..

Comment: I "solved" it. Load Ubuntu at recovery mode, enable network and run as root, type: "apt-get install nvidia-current" and wait for a long time (I slept while). If the terminal say something of encrypt restart your Ubuntu at normal mode, the only problem  is that the dual monitor setup is like "horizontal scrolling" between them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it'll really work for you but here's what I did:

1. Restart Ubuntu at Recovery Mode and enable networking.
2. Run the terminal with the root option and type

   ```
   apt-get install nvidia-current
   ```
3. Wait and see if there's an encrypt thing in your terminal. After you see that encrypt thing, restart your Ubuntu normally.

Comment: Unfortunately, for me it says `nvidia-current: Depends: nvidia-304 but it is not going to be installed`, and won't install `nvidia-current`